# Text Picker Component

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, widget, selector

Does something exist for Android? I am looking for something equivalent to HTML's  tag. I see things like NumberPicker, but I can't see any way to have a basic drop down selector.

I am aware of ListPreference, but I want to use it outside the context of a PreferenceActivity and inside arbitrary views. Anyone?

Comment: I realize I could just create a button that opens a Dialog with a ListView inside of it, but that seems way too complex. I basically just want a View implementation that is equivalent to ListPreference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for the [spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html), maybe?

Comment: Yeah, talk about a counter-intuitive name.